# Why is my migration calling the wrong DbContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have multiple DbContexts (Main, Child) and everyone of them has its own DbSets. 
(These DbContexts have their own migrations)
Now I am creating a new DbContext called "CondorDBUsers" that will have also its own DbSets.  In Configration.cs (Migrations folder) I set this context as:

```
 internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<CondorExtreme3.DAL.CondorDBUsers>
```

and also

```
protected override void Seed(CondorExtreme3.DAL.CondorDBUsers context){ }
```

the problem here is when I create a new migration, I get errors "Main and Child migration are pending", then when I say "update-database -force" its updates my "CondorDBUsers" database with tables from "Child" context.

My question: 
How is it possible to  create a new context with a new migration that contains only the tables from context I set in Configration.cs ?

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, thank you.

Comment: Stack Overflow automatically lists possible answers to the bottom right of your question. That is where I found it :-)